# Validating xamarin.forms picker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I use this code to get the selected item on my picker:

`var loanType = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];`

I want to validate the picker when nothing is selected but it returns:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
```

I understand that it's because nothing is selected, so I wanted to ask if there is any workaround to this. I use syntax `picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];` instead of `pickerPaymentMode.SelectedIndex` because the picker's item source is from a list coming from a JSON response via API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing is selected in the picker, the value of `picker.SelectedIndex` is **-1**.

So you can check everytime you use `picker.SelectedIndex`:

```
    if (picker.SelectedIndex != null && picker.SelectedIndex >=0)
    {
        var loanType = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(picker.SelectedIndex);
    }
```